# Swipe Gesture issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i have added two swipegesture on my image view .one for right and one for left. all i want is that when use click on any image and swipe it in left or right direction the image change accordingly as we do in our phone gallery. but when i swipe to left or right only one time image change after that nothing happens. all these images are coming from array and array name is getdataarray. here is my code

.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightgesture;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftgesture;
- (IBAction)handleswipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender;
```

.m file

```
-(void)viewdidload 


_rightgesture= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleswipe:)];

    _leftgesture= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleswipe:)];


- (IBAction)handleswipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    int imageindex = (int) selectedimageindex;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

    switch (direction) {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            imageindex++;
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            imageindex--;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (imageindex > -1 || imageindex < getdataarray.count) {
        [fullimageview sd_setImageWithURL:[getdataarray objectAtIndex: imageindex] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is selectimageIndex ? I grass the issue from selectimageIndex ;

Because you swipe the imageview once , the method 'handleswipe:' will run a once . so imageindex allways equal selectimageIndex .  Please break a point  to look the imageindex value .

--

### - edit again

```
 -(void)viewdidload 
{

_rightgesture= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleswipe:)];

    _leftgesture= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleswipe:)];

// this code changed. _imageindex is global property .
    _imageindex = (int) selectedimageindex;
}

- (IBAction)handleswipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

    switch (direction) {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
             if (_imageindex<getdataarray.count) _imageindex++; break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
             if (_imageindex>0)_imageindex--;   break;
       default: break;
   }

   if (_imageindex > -1 && _imageindex < getdataarray.count) {
       [fullimageview sd_setImageWithURL:[getdataarray objectAtIndex:_imageindex] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
   }
  }
```

Comment: selectedimageindex is the index no of the image in which user clicks , this is collection view cell in which images is displaying
getselectedimageindexno = (int) indexPath.row;

Comment: int imageindex = (int) selectedimageindex;

Look at this line . You imageindex is always equal selectedimageindex . Because selectedimageindex can’t change , So you swipe imageview , the imageindex can change .

Comment: so how can I fix this ?

Comment: I have edit the answer , Hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with when you reach to imageindex ==0  you should stop decrement and when you are index == getdataarray.count you should stop increment

```
- (IBAction)handleswipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

int imageindex = (int) selectedimageindex;

UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

switch (direction) {

    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        if imageindex<0
        {
             imageindex++;
        }
        imageindex++;
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        if imageindex>getdataarray.count
        {
             imageindex--;
        }

        break;

    default:
        break;
}

if (imageindex > -1 && imageindex < getdataarray.count) {
    [fullimageview sd_setImageWithURL:[getdataarray objectAtIndex: imageindex] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
}
```

**And** you should Use && operator instead of OR operator

Comment: not working .. still the same issue only on first time swipe is working after that nothing happens